# Trouble with the differential in the Mobius Strip

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $f:[0,2\pi]\times (-1,1)\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ given by:
$f((\theta, t))=(2\textrm{cos}\theta+t\textrm{cos}(\theta/2)\textrm{cos}(\theta),2\textrm{sin}\theta+t\textrm{cos}(\theta/2)\textrm{sin}\theta,t\textrm{sin}(\theta/2))$.

One has that $f(\mathbb{R}\times (-1,1))=M$ where $M$ is the Mobius strip.

In the "Comprehensive introduction into differential geometry, vol 1, 3 ed." he computes $Df_{(0,0)}(0,1)$ and $Df_{(2\pi,0)}(0,1)$, but I cannot understand in which sense, since $[0,2\pi]$ is not a smooth manifold (see page 70 in the book).
I have thought to take the extension $f\colon \mathbb{R}\times (-1,1) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. But... the resulting vector would be in $T_{f(0,\theta)}\mathbb{R}^3$  instead of $T_{f(0,\theta)}M$... I am confused.

Comment: Since $M$ is a submanifold of $\Bbb R^3$, $TM$ embeds naturally in $T\Bbb R^3$.